# How to perform an action just after animation of AnimatorSet stops?

Tags: android, animation, onclicklistener, nineoldandroids

I have placed the following code in a for loop:

```
set8.playTogether(
       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball4, "translationX", x1, xn),
       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball4, "translationY", y1, yn),
       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball8, "translationX", xn, x1),
       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball8, "translationY", yn, y1)
);
set8.setDuration(t).start();
```

Before every iteration of the for loop, I want to wait for the animation of previous iteration to complete. Is there any way to do that?

In my project, I have an onclick listener on an image. I also want that onclicklistener to be nonfunctional until the animation is completed in the above code.

Is there any method to do these things?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html

You can add a Animator.AnimatorListener to your animation:

```
set8.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // animation is done, handle it here
    }
```

you can find another example here:
[How to position a view so the click works after an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022387/how-to-position-a-view-so-the-click-works-after-an-animation?rq=1)

EDIT: Full example of what you are looking for:

```
int totalSteps = 8;
    for (int i=0; i<totalSteps; i++) {
        // .. create the animation set
        set8.addListener(new MyAnimatorListenerAdapter(i, new onAnimationStpeDoneListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStepDone(int step) {
                if (step < totalSteps) {
                    // start the next animation
                } else {
                    // all steps are done, enable the clicks... 
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    public interface onAnimationStpeDoneListener {
        public void onAnimationStepDone(int step);
    }

    public class MyAnimatorListenerAdapter extends AnimatorListenerAdapter {
        private int mStep;
        private onAnimationStpeDoneListener mDelegate;

        public MyAnimatorListenerAdapter(int step, onAnimationStpeDoneListener listener) {
            mStep = step;
            mDelegate = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            if (mDelegate != null) {
                mDelegate.onAnimationStepDone(mStep);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but, how to go to the next iteration using this method? Can you simplify this..  @ziv

Answer (score 0):

Just use handler of that particular duration.

Code:

```
int i=n;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      set8.playTogether(
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball4, "translationX", x1, xn),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball4, "translationY", y1, yn),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball8, "translationX", xn, x1),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball8, "translationY", yn, y1)
      );
      set8.start();
      
      //Action

      i--;
      if(i!=0){
         new Handler().postDelayed(this,t);
      }
   }
},t);
```